# How to flatten a layered dataset in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, flatten

Say for example there is dataframe A:

```
A
col0  col1  col2
'a0'  'a'   'A'
'b0'  'b'   'A'
'c0'  'c'   'A'
'de0' 'd'   'B'
'sas' 'ef'  'B'
```

How can I get to dataframe B?

```
B
col1 col2
'a0'  'A'
'a' 'A'
'b0' 'A'
'b'  'A'
'c0' 'A'
'c'  'A'
'de0''B'
'd'  'B'
'sas''B'
'ef' 'B'
```

Any help would be apreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: df.melt(['col0,'col1'])

Comment: I think `df.mel('col2')` works better.

Comment: The other comments have it -- look at the documentation for [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html). Examples are included there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to keep exact names and order of columns from your example try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col0': ('a0', 'b0', 'c0', 'de0', 'sas'),
                   'col1': ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ef'),
                   'col2': ('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B')})

sorted_df = sorted_df = df.melt('col2', value_name='col1').drop(columns='variable')\
.sort_values('col1').reset_index(drop=True).sort_index(axis=1)

print(df)

  col0 col1 col2
0   a0    a    A
1   b0    b    A
2   c0    c    A
3  de0    d    B
4  sas   ef    B

print(sorted_df)

  col1 col2
0    a    A
1   a0    A
2    b    A
3   b0    A
4    c    A
5   c0    A
6    d    B
7  de0    B
8   ef    B
9  sas    B
```